# How to disable 'jQuery UI Layout plugin' in mobile/tablet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

In designing a web (HTML/Javascript/Angular) UI, I have a left pane which contains a treeview and the centre pane (on the right hand side).

I am using jQuery UI Layout plugin (layout.jquery-dev.net/index.cfm). I have a west and centre panes and it works fine.

```
<div id="centralContainer" >
        <div class="ui-layout-west">
            <div>LEFT</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-layout-center">
            <div>MAIN</div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

but when the end user uses **mobile or tablet** to view the page, I want to disable the layout and replace it with Bootstrap responsive columns. Something like this:

```
<div id="centralContainer" class="row">
        <div class="ui-layout-west" class="col-sm-4">
            <div>LEFT</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-layout-center" class="col-sm-8">
            <div>MAIN</div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

What is the best way to do this? I don't know how to solve this? 
There are several scenario that the desktop UI should be different from Mobile UI and I don't what the best way to handle it is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for a way to detect whether it's a mobile device or not?
That can be done by

```
   var useragent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
   if (useragent.search("blackberry") > -1 
   ||  useragent.search("android") > -1
   ||  useragent.search("iphone") > -1 
   ||  useragent.search("webos") > -1  
   ||  useragent.search("ipad") > -1){

       window.location.href ="mobileindex.html";
   }
```

Or use the scripts from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/